# JRE / Windows version compatibility

Tags: windows, compatibility, java

I'm creating an installer for a Java application for Windows. The customers wants to bundle the JRE with the installation (I know that's kind of frowned upon, but it's not up to me). 
If I bundle the JRE7 32bit windows version, will it work on all Windows version (XP- 8, both 32 and 64bit)?

Comment: Not sure this is on topic as it isn't programming related. Might get a better answer on one of the other Q&As like super user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Oracle Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/windows/windows-system-requirements.html), JRE 7 32 bit is supported on

**Microsoft Windows 32-Bit**

- Windows 7
- Windows Vista
- Windows Server 2008
- Windows XP

**Microsoft Windows x64, 32-Bit Mode**

- Windows 7
- Windows Vista
- Windows Server 2008
- Windows XP

**Microsoft Windows x64, 64-Bit Mode**

- Windows 7
- Windows Server 2008
- Windows Server 2008 R2
- Windows Vista
- Windows XP

Windows 8 does not appear on Oracle official site on the certified OS list. My guess is that Windows 8 is backward-compatible and JRE7 32 bit could run there too.

Comment: Thank you, I was just unsure about whether these are the versions that are supported by different JRE version, but it seems like there are only two JRE versions for Windows versions, and the 32bit one seems to support them all.